# julia to regex match lines in a file like grep

Tags: julia

I would like to see a code snippet of julia that will read a file and return lines (string type) that match a regular expression.

I welcome multiple techniques, but output should be equivalent to the following:

```
$> grep -E ^AB[AJ].*TO' 'webster-unabridged-dictionary-1913.txt'

ABACTOR
ABATOR
ABATTOIR
ABJURATORY
```

*I'm using GNU grep 3.1 here, and the first line of each entry in the file is the all caps word on its own.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favored solution uses a simple loop and is very easy to understand.

```
julia> open("webster-unabridged-dictionary-1913.txt") do f
           for i in eachline(f)
               if ismatch(r"^AB[AJ].*TO", i) println(i) end
           end
       end

ABACTOR
ABATOR
ABATTOIR
ABJURATORY
```

#### notes

- Lines with tab separations have the tabs preserved (no literal output of '\t')
- my source file in this example has the dictionary words in all caps alone on one line above the definition; the complete line is returned.
- the file I/O operation is wrapped in a [do block syntax structure](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments-1), which expresses an anonymous function more conveniently than lamba `x -> f(x)` syntax for multi-line functions. This is particularly expressive with the file `open()` command, defined with a `try-finally-close` operation when called with a function as an argument.
- [Julia docs: Strings/Regular Expressions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/strings/#Regular-Expressions-1)

  - regex objects take the form `r"<regex_literal_here>"`
  - the regex itself is a string
  - based on perl [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/)
  - matches become regex match objects

example

```
julia> reg = r"^AB[AJ].*TO";
julia> typeof(reg)
Regex

julia> test = match(reg, "ABJURATORY")
RegexMatch("ABJURATO")

julia> typeof(test)
RegexMatch
```

Comment: `ismatch()` is deprecated in julia > 1.0. Instead `occursin()` should be used.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the `filter` function to do this in one line.

```
filter(line -> ismatch(r"^AB[AJ].*TO",line),readlines(open("webster-unabridged-dictionary-1913.txt")))
```

`filter` applies a function returning a Boolean to an array, and only returns those elements of the array which are `true`. The function in this case is an anonymous function `line -> ismatch(r"^AB[AJ].*TO",line)"`, which basically says to call each element of the array being filtered (each line, in this case) `line`.

I think this might not be the best solution for very large files as the entire file needs to be loaded into memory before filtering, but for this example it seems to be just as fast as the for loop using `eachline`. Another difference is that this solution returns the results as an array rather than printing each of them, which depending on what you want to do with the matches might be a good or bad thing.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion about `readlines()` consuming the entire file and loading an array before filtering. Does it not require a `close()` operation? Returning an array can be useful, in this case I wanted to replicate the behavior of grep; i got the idea from [this regex tutorial blog post](https://blog.patricktriest.com/you-should-learn-regex/)

Comment: That's a helpful blog post for comparing programming languages, thanks! If you wanted to print the resulting array like grep you could do `filter(line -> ismatch(r"^AB[AJ].*TO",line),readlines(open("webster-unabridged-dictionary-1913.txt"))) .|> println;`. I don't think it requires `close()` - since the stream is never named, I'm not sure how you could tell `close` what to close.

Answer (score 2):

Just putting `;` in front is Julia's way to using commandline commands so this works in Julia's REPL

```
;grep -E ^AB[AJ].*TO' 'webster-unabridged-dictionary-1913.txt'
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Helpful tip in general, but i know how to solve this with ‘grep’ already.

Comment: @Merlin good point of view for someone in the future coming into this cold